# OpenGL orthographic projection Oy resizing

Tags: qt, opengl, orthographic

I'm woring on OpenGL 2D application using Qt, and ran into a problem with the orthogonal projection. So, the whole problem is explained in the pictures.

When I change the the window's width, so the size of the object is constant:
[image]
[image]

But when the height is changed...
[image]

Here's the vertex shader:

```
in vec4 vertex;
uniform mediump mat4 view;

void main( void )
{
    gl_Position = view * vertex;
}
```

And here's the code of resize function:

```
void resizeGL( int width, int height ) override
{
    glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );

    const auto aratio = float( width ) / float( height );
    modelMatrix.setToIdentity();
    modelMatrix.ortho( -aratio, aratio, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's exactly what that code is supposed to do, what do you want to happen?

Comment: if you want to keep the object the same size, then you need to relate the orthographic matrix to the size of the window, not just the ratio (as is usually the wanted behavior). So something like `float scalefac = 1.0f/500.0f; modelMatrix.ortho( -width/scalefac, width/scalefac, -height/scalefac, height/scalefac, -1.0f, 1.0f );`